# How to implement unobtrusive method forwarding?

Tags: javascript, forwarding, oop

```
var o = new SomethingComplex;

var o.foo = new SomeThing; // we have o.foo.doSomething

setUpForwarding(o, o.foo);

o.doSomething(); // calls o.doSomething if exist, else o.foo.doSomething
```

How would one go about setting up unobtrusive method forwarding? Using ES5 techniques is perfectly fine. I can imagine this being impossible in IE6

I'm not looking for a method like `o.call("doSomething");` I want it to be completely unobtrusive.

Also editing `.__proto__` so you can throw `o.foo` in the prototype chain is cheating and is disallowed. Overwriting `o` with `o.foo` in it's natural prototype chain is allowed but `o` is not limited in complexity.

Are there any viable options left?

I just remember the existance of [node-proxy](https://github.com/isaacs/node-proxy) which allows you to extend [node.js](http://www.nodejs.org/) to implement proxies (Implemented in C++). This provides catch-all functionality and can probably be ported to other SS JS.

Comment: Does it have to be dynamic?  Otherwise, why not just modify "o", merging in all the properties of "o.foo"?

Comment: @Pointy I wanted to avoid composition but use aggregation and forwarding. Argueably if I'm using aggregation & forwarding I should use composition instead and it's a smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does not have 'catch all' handlers, although it is under consideration for a future version.

You could solve this specific issue by having `setUpForwarding` iterate through all function member of `foo` and then create a forwarding function in `o` with the same name. This will only work for functions though.

Comment: you can easily forward properties with ES5 `Object.defineProperty`. I was hoping there was something nice I could do. Also the use of `.__noSuchMethod__` is do-able in moz.